# AngularJS loading modules

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a really hard time trying to make modules working on an app I'm building.

This is the main file

main.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('clientPortalPublic',[
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngAnimate',
    'clientPortalPublic.components'
    ]);

 angular.module('clientPortalPublic.components',[]);
```

And I have another file switch-login-effect.js

'use strict';

```
angular.module('clientPortalPublic.components').directive('switchLoginEffect',['$timeout', function($timeout){

    //Content removed for clarification
}]);
```

The order that those files are being loaded is:

```
 <script type="application/javascript" src="public/components/switch-login-effect.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="public/main.js"></script>
```

I know the switch-login-effect.js should be loaded later, since is requiring the main module, but it's being loaded dynamically and I don't control the order. BUT using manual bootstrapping shouldn't angular deal with it?

This is how I'm bootstrapping it

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['clientPortalPublic']);
});
```

If I run the code above I get:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'clientPortalPublic.components' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to load `main.js` before `switch-login-effect.js` because you are trying to register a directive on a module that does not exist yet.

Comment: It's not clear to me why Mustela wrote this: ""I know the switch-login-effect.js should be loaded later, since is requiring the main module, but it's being loaded dynamically and I don't control the order."

Comment: @PSL I can't control the scripts order inclusion. That's way I'm trying to bootstrap it manually. But angular seems to be trying to use the module as soon as the file is loaded, not when I run "angular.bootstrap".

Comment: break switch-login into another module. Name it something like `clientPortalPublic.components.switchLogin`. Then just add it as an extra dependency for components.

Comment: but doing that would lost the meaning of musing modules actually. And if I would have 50 elements under components.xxx and I would need them all in another component I should have to add one by one...

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a directive on a non-existant module when `switch-login-effect.js` loads first.  It looks like you are trying to dynamically control what elements are included in the `clientPortalPublic.components` module simply by adding or removing scripts, but I don't think angular's dependencies are set up for that.  A main reason to have those dependencies is to know exactly what you are getting.

The `clientPortalPublic.components` module should be defined in one script file if possible.  If you have various components you can create different modules for each, but the definition of your application module should know what it is getting by the dependencies it requires.  That would cause debugging headaches for one reason, "Why is my directive not working?  I'm loading the components module..." (but you missed a script file you have no way to know that you need)

I ***really*** don't advise creating your app this way, but if you are dead-set you could catch the error and create the module at the start of each individual component file (and in your main.js in case you don't actually have any components but still want to require the module) so it doesn't matter which one is loaded first:

```
try {
    angular.module('clientPortalPublic.components');
} catch (err) {
    angular.module('clientPortalPublic.components',[]);
}
```

Or more simply just uses javascript to see if it's been executed:

```
var componentsModule = componentsModule || 
    angular.module('clientPortalPublic.components',[]);
```

Comment: But how do you deal with elements (different files) under the module clientPortalPublic.components? 

Also this code

`
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['clientPortalPublic']);
});
`


shouldn't wait until everything is ready?

Answer (score 0):

After reading some angular good practices and paying more attention to angular seed, I have it working.

THe thing is that they recommend to do the following when you have an structure similar to:

```
app/
app/components
app/components/component1
app/components/component2

app.js => angular.module('main',['main.components']);
app/components/components.js => angular.module('main.components',['main.components.component1', 'main.components.component2']);
app/components/component1.js => angular.module('main.components.component1',[]);
app/components/component2.js => angular.module('main.components.component2',[]);
```

Having that structure make sense and works perfectly.

:)